# What ways are there to achieve persistent, shareable storage in html & javascript alone?

Tags: javascript, json, html, local-storage, data-storage

**Edit:**
Let me try to clarify with a use case.  I would love to be able to run a simple chat-box on an html/javascript page without running my -own- server.  I can write the chat application's javascript just fine, but don't have a solution that allows me to store the data to make the chat messages visible to all browsing users.  So my app would accept data, post it to a third-party data store (Ideally just in json format), and poll from the data store for updates periodically.  That's not the only thing I would use such a json storage service/json storage engine for, but it is the clearest example.

---

I am backing away from server-side programming a little bit as html5 comes to the forefront, and exploring how much I can do with just html and javascript, in terms of functionality that I would previously have to achieve with a html/php/sql server stack.  For example, on this nascent html5 site: http://tersh.royronalds.com/ I'm reusing flickr for image hosting and tumblr for blog post hosting.  However, just as one example, I now find myself wanting to code a dynamic todo list, something where items can be added and ticked off as completed, and publicly displayed during that time.  Another example might be a simple, persistent chat box.

For example, instead of using ajax to push boolean data and text about chat messages and changes to a php script that would then store the data in a mysql database, I'd love to push and pull the data to/from a third-party store that provides somewhat the same type of functionality as the localstorage API, but for json.

So I'd like to solve that using some method of storage with a public js API, e.g. some method for storing json, or any end format that supports strings and numbers really, and is store-able and retrievable, similar to localStorage, except persistent and shareable.

What public technologies/solutions are there for such a thing?

Comment: basically you just need to be able to read and write to and from a db using only js?

Comment: maybe try the google drive sdk (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/)? I'm guessing that whatever public general-purpose thing you go with will be much more complicated than standing up a simple and cheap shared hosing environment with a few lines of code to wrap up the database. In modern sites, the backends are turning into nothing more than json pumps but they are still there...

Comment: Yeah, only js on the site.  Obviously the storage engine could be whatever was necessary on the third-party server though I expect it wouldn't have to be complex.

I'll check out the google drive stuff, see if it'd do what I'm looking for.
While yes, I expect working with someone else's api will be more complicated to implement, it would mean that I wouldn't have to run php/apache/mysql or even node.js/mongodb on a server per site instance, and the individuals the site is for could host the page anywhere that hosts static html files, while still having robust functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few options for this, even if they are not very nice, or well developed.

First off, the one most closely related to a server-side database is a Web SQL Database. This is not a recommended feature by the W3C (it does not use SQLite as a backend), however, it is currently supported in Chrome, Opera, Safari, and Firefox (with an add-on).

[Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/)

Second, we have Indexed Database API's. These are only supported by Chrome and Firefox. (And IE 10, but who cares?) It is more different from a normal database, but is a recommended method by the W3C.

[Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/)

Third, we have local storage. This is not a database-like system, it is more similar to cookies. However, these local storage items are better than cookies because they are each a key-value pair (and very intuitive to use, i might add). For example:

```
// Store value on the browser permanently
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
// Retrieve value
localStorage.getItem('key');
//Remove value
localStorage.removeItem('key');
//This is just a small selection of actions you can perform
```

[Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/)
[Helpful Resource](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-storage)

Fourth, you should maybe take a quick peek at offline HTML. This is a system where select files in your site are downloaded by the browser, and can be used offline. I don't think this is useful for you, but check it out.

[Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html)
[Helpful Guide](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html)

As you might be able to tell, I've had more experience in the last two than the first. I hope I was helpful anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with self-only storage and it's good to be reminded of the options available, I especially love localStorage, great for saving settings, but not share-able, of course.  A great use-case to explain an example of the type of the problem that I'm trying to solve is coding a very simple chat box visible to all users, without running a full server stack just to save a few lines of chat.